# Font Awesome Implementation into ASP.NET TextBox Server Control

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

http://www.petcenters.com/painting-estimate is a test page with Bootstrap enabled ASP.NET Controls utilizing CssClass Selector.

I have attempted to implement Font Awesome Classes into ASP.NET TextBox Controls following guidelines illustrated within:
[Bootstrap Documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups)

```
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
  <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2">@example.com</span>
</div>
```

A Bootstrap Template that I'm using shows their implementation of: [Font Awesome with HTML Form Tags](http://htmlstream.com/preview/unify-v1.7/page_contact_advanced.php)

```
<section class="col col-6">
   <label class="label">Company</label>
   <label class="input">
      <i class="icon-append fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
      <input type="text" name="company" id="company">
   </label>
</section>
```

I have attempted to replicate with both scenarios for ASP.NET Textbox Server Control.

```
<div class="input-group col-md-6 clearfix">
   <label for="txtGenCompany">Company</label>
   <asp:TextBox ID="txtGenCompany" name="company" CssClass="form-control" aria-describedby="addon1" placeholder="Enter Company" runat="server" TabIndex="2"></asp:TextBox>
    <span class="input-group-addon" id="addon1">
       <i class="icon-append fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
    </span>
</div>
```

I believe I'm missing something with either "span" or "i" [Company TextBox](http://www.petcenters.com/painting-estimate)

If anyone has any idea I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you need is

HTML

```
<div class="input-group input-group-md">
  <lable>Company</lable>
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtGenCompany" name="company" CssClass="form-control" aria-describedby="addon1" placeholder="Enter Company" runat="server" TabIndex="2"></asp:TextBox>
  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i></span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
lable {
 display: table-caption;
 white-space: nowrap;
}

.input-group {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

[image: RESULT]

PS: It's not good to have too many visual guides for getting input,
here we have 3:

- the lable
- the placeholder
- the font-awesome icon

try to reduce them if you can.

Comment: I have to use ASP.NET Textbox Server Control

Comment: try moving the `<span>...</span>` portion before ASP.NET textbox and get rid of the `<lable>` tag or move it outside the div

Comment: just moving or getting rid of the `<lable></lable>` tag will also do the trick.

Comment: so moving the Label outside of the Div worked for the 2nd Textbox, however, trying to add this to both Textboxes within the same row didn't work.

Comment: If you don't want to re-position the label, add this to your css `label {
  display: table-caption;
  white-space: nowrap;
}`

Comment: also make sure that the other divs have the same structure and classes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76320/discussion-between-ashesh-and-paul).